# How to get closest date from today from multiple columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I need two `col` 1st one shows the closest date and 2nd one shows the name of the `col`

```
d = {'col1': ["id1","id2"] 'Stage 1': [26-01-2021, 04-01-2021],'Stage 2': [27-01-2021, 02-10-2025]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

image reference

Actual

[image]

Requirement

[image]

I tried

```
date=datetime.date.today()
idx = plc.index[df[['Stage 1','Stage 2']].index.get_loc(date, 
    method='nearest')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting the dates to datetime you can pass it to a function that populates both new columns in one go:

```
import pandas 
import datetime
d = {'col1': ["id1","id2"], 'Stage 1': ['26-01-2021', '04-01-2021'],'Stage 2': ['27-01-2021', '02-10-2025']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Stage 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 1'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Stage 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 2'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
date=pd.to_datetime(datetime.date.today())

def get_date(row):
    date_range = row[['Stage 1', 'Stage 2']]
    closest_date_key = abs(date - date_range).argmin()
    closest_date = date_range[closest_date_key]
    column_name = date_range.keys()[closest_date_key]
    return pd.Series((closest_date, column_name))

df[['Requirement 1', 'Requirement 2']] = df.apply(lambda row:get_date(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
|    | col1   | Stage 1             | Stage 2             | Requirement 1       | Requirement 2   |
|---:|:-------|:--------------------|:--------------------|:--------------------|:----------------|
|  0 | id1    | 2021-01-26 00:00:00 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00 | 2021-01-27 00:00:00 | Stage 2         |
|  1 | id2    | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 2025-10-02 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | Stage 1         |
```

Comment: Thanks. It was quick. Just "today" should be replaced by "date". It was really helpful.

Comment: You're right - I updated the answer. Feel free to upvote answers to your question and please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 1):

The following would get you there:

First convert your dates to `datetimes` so you can use them in comparison operations:

```
df['Stage 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 1'])
df['Stage 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Stage 2'])
```

Then find the position of the closest date for example using:

```
closest = np.argmin([abs(df['Stage 1'].dt.date - date), 
                     abs(df['Stage 2'].dt.date - date)], axis=1)
```

And use these positions to get the names of your columns. You can assign that value in your first new column `Requirement 1`

```
df['Requirement 1'] = df.columns[-2:][closest]
```

You can then use the column name in `Requirement 1` to get the original date that was closest:

```
df['Requirement 2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Requirement 1']].date(), axis=1)
```

My output looks then like:

```
  col1    Stage 1    Stage 2 Requirement 1 Requirement 2
0  id1 2021-01-26 2025-01-27       Stage 1    2021-01-26
1  id2 2025-04-01 2019-02-10       Stage 2    2019-02-10
```